# Most efficient way to compute differences and intersection of two sets in Python

Tags: python, set, set-operations

Let's say we have two sets `s1` and `s2`.

I require three different sets based on these two sets:

1. Set of elements that exist in `s1` but not in `s2`.
2. Set of elements that exist in `s2` but not in `s1`.
3. Set of elements that exist in both `s1` and `s2`.

These could be easily computed as follows:

```py
s1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
s2 = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7}

o1 = s1 - s2
o2 = s2 - s1
o3 = s1 & s2
```

Is there a way to compute these sets more efficiently? I imagine the different set operations have multiple internal processing steps in common, so there might be redundancy.

Comment: I don't think its possible to do in less then `O(n)`. Which is what python does, since lookup in sets is `O(1)`. Don't need to worry about unless the operation actually takes significant time.

Comment: I would trust the implementors of the standard library to have done a better work (more efficient) than what I could do in plain Python. What are you really after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that these operations are implemented in C in the core part of the language, I think there's pretty much nothing you can do to speed these operations up in custom-written code.

But...

Since `s1 - s2` is the same as `s1 - (s1 & s2)`, you could calculate `o3` first and use this smaller set in the difference operations:

```
s1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
s2 = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7}

o3 = s1 & s2
o1 = s1 - o3
o2 = s2 - o3
```

I doubt it will make much of a difference, since set lookup and insertion are O(1), but it's conceivable that operations over smaller sets are still slightly faster.